# Material Tab Button Overriding Modal

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using [material tabs](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview) and each tab has a filter menu but the problem is this when this menu opens the background tab button override it .

[image]

Please let me know how can I fix this using css?

**MainComponent**

```
<mat-tab-group >

 <mat-tab *ngFor="let tab of tabs; let index = index" [label]="tab">

  <div *ngIf="tab=='TBS'">


   //This is filter modal 

    <sitesearchfilter-menu [@slideInOut]="menuState" (closeMenuEvent)="toggleMenu()"  [TBSDd]="tbsFilter"  [tab]="tab"   (TBSReportEvent)="getTBSReport($event)"></sitesearchfilter-menu>

     //This is tab stuff

    <app-tbstbl *ngIf="showTBSTbl" [model]="siteModel" [TBSCol]="" [TBSData]="TBSDataSet"></app-tbstbl>

    </div>

   </mat-tab>
```

**Filter**

```
<div *ngIf="TrackReport">

        <div fxLayout="row">
                <div fxFlex.gt-sm="100%">
                    <mat-card>
                        <mat-card-content>
                            <mat-card-title>

                                    <button   mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="closeEvent()" type="button"><mat-icon>filter_list</mat-icon>
                                        Filter</button>

                            </mat-card-title>


                            <form 
                            #dF="ngForm"
                            (ngSubmit)="submitTBS(dF.value)"
                            >


                    <FORM STUFF HERE>                        


                        </form>


                        </mat-card-content>
                    </mat-card>
                </div>
            </div>


    </div>
```

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: set z-index icon lower than of your modal

Comment: material defines their own z-index for their components, sometimes these lead to such effects. Adapt the z-index and you should be fine.

Comment: Some how you changed the z-index of  `cdk-overlay-container` or  `cdk-overlay-backdrop` if know inspect these values and compare it with the default on on official site of angular materiel

Comment: @Awais I have tried this but no luck

Comment: Can you share your code on stackblitz?https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: Would that I could but its confidential.